# Android FusedLocationProviderClient problem

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mobile

I have been following a tutorial however it is quite old and uses the deprecated googleApiClient. Weirdly though, when I use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

It works as should do by displaying the location on the map. I assumed it wouldn't work and when debugging before it wouldn't build. 
I have tried to impelement a new way using the updating version whereby the fusedLocationApi isn't included. 
Attached are the working version with fusedLocationApi & googleClientApi, and the newer code which builds but isn't showing the location on the map when the app builds.

Maybe there is something missing in the updated code that isn't producing the location to show on the map??

I'm new to Android to any help appreciated :)

Old Working Version - https://pastebin.com/VG4AUJrv

Updated Not Working Version - https://pastebin.com/xa674c5f

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // add here
                fusedLocationProviderClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            }else
            {
                checkLocationPermission()
            }
        }
```

Your problem is here.
When you grant an application permission it will not perform a location search so you need to write a method to do it if you have granted it permission.

Comment: Still a bit confused, so after the if statement I need to create a method which returns the location? Haven't I got something already which is searching for the location or am I wrong saying that? In an example I am looking at https://github.com/SimCoderYoutube/UberClone/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/simcoder/uber/DriverMapActivity.java , they do not have anything in the if statement

Comment: So I changed it to this: `fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled();` but no marker shows on map